# Asp.net MVC5 How can I shorten the URL of item so that It uses less space on database . I get the following error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Problem description:  As an example 
[Ebay link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-MacBook-Silver-13-320GB-HDD-2-3GHz-i5-4GB-OS-X-High-Sierra-2017-Office/263591535536?hash=item3d5f47a3b0:g:D4AAAOSwKIdaXhqt)

Can be shortened to https://www.ebay.com/itm//263591535536, so that it takes less space on the database .
I try to capture the full `url` in `Razer` page and then in the Controller I try to shorten it .
Then I get the validation error .
My code is:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(home).State = EntityState.Modified;
    home.DetailUrl = RealHouses2.Models.Miscellaneous.RemoveExtraCharFromUrl(home.DetailUrl);

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return View(home);
```

Error message is:

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
>     HResult=0x80131920
>     Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: What makes you think that error is due to the length of the URL? If so why not just increase the size of the database field?

Comment: Idea is the reduce the size of the database. I am planning to use shared hosting which has limited database space.

Comment: Does the funciton produce the shortend URL that you want? The issue could be another column in your database

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,  Nick.McDermaid. Yes the issue is my method to reduce the URL length does not produce the correct url. So it produce a validation error. That corrected my mistake.